# Reduce C# Application CPU Usage

Tags: c#, tcp

I am creating a program that will TCP Event Receiver. Every time I start the program having is CPU consumption 30% and try to publish it and try to run multiple application  it gradually consume 100% of my CPU Usage

```
namespace TCPIPReceiver
```

{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
SimpleTcpServer server;
SqlConnection con;
BackgroundWorker backgroundworker1;
Thread INCOMING;

```
    bool rxv = false;
    string rxvmsg;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadit();
    }
    private void loadit()
    {
        server = new SimpleTcpServer();
        server.Delimiter = 0x13;
        server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
        server.DataReceived += server_datarx;
        backgroundworker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        INCOMING = new Thread(INCOMINGTHREAD);

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if(rxv)
            {
                rxv = false;
                INCOMING = new Thread(INCOMINGTHREAD);
                INCOMING.Start();
            }
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void server_datarx(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
    {
        rxvmsg = e.MessageString;
        rxv = true;
        SetText(rxvmsg);
        e.ReplyLine("\u0006");
    }

    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.textBox2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            if (text != null)
            {
                this.textBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                this.textBox2.AppendText(text);
            }
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if((textBox1.Text == "") || (textBox3.Text == ""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All fields are required","System Notification",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            startit();
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

        }
    }

    private void startit()
    {
        if (button1.Text == "Start")
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(textBox3.Text);
            if(connectionchecker())
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                server.Start(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
                button1.Text = "Stop";
                SetText("Established Database Connection");
                settingslocker(true);
                

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check database connection", "Database connection error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        else if (button1.Text == "Stop")
        {
            server.Stop();
            button1.Text = "Start";
            settingslocker(false);
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    private void settingslocker(bool indi)
    {
        if(indi)
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private bool connectionchecker()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            con.Close();
            return true;
        } catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My question is how do I reduce CPU usage running multiple same application I build?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have an infinite loop. You haven't shown it so we can't help you. But `BackgroundWorker` is effectively deprecated, you should use `async`, especially with IO such as a TCP server.

Comment: Please post more of your code to assist us in helping you. e.g. what calls `startit()` and how often?  Show us the handler for `backgroundWorker1`.  [mcve]

Comment: Also, only use threads/BackgroundWorker for _CPU-bound_ operations.   Databases and TCP are examples of _I/O-bound_ operations where to use a thread is wasteful as it spends most of the time blocked and waiting for I/O to complete.  Consider using  contemporary `async/await` which when used with async-aware code won't use a thread **at all** due to I/O Completion Ports (IOCP).

Comment: I would note that blocking inside IO methods should not cause high CPU usage. So it seem likely that your loop that read/writes is *not* blocking, creating a tight loop that burns CPU. The easy but bad way to fix it is to insert a Thread.Sleep. The much better way is to use async IO as others have mentioned.

Comment: @Charlieface it seems the problem with the Backgroundworker after running the program
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if(rxv)
            {
                rxv = false;
                INCOMING = new Thread(INCOMINGTHREAD);
                INCOMING.Start();
            }
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @MickyD already update the code for to see what seems to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**TL; DR:** your code is inefficiently handling TCP I/O by spamming new reader threads.  This can lead to high RAM usage, page faults and ultimately high CPU-use due to Windows memory compression

---

Re update, I can see now that your `BackgroundWorker` is **spamming a new thread** to `INCOMINGTHREAD()` whenever *data is ready to be read on the `SimpleTcpServer`*.

Apart from being highly inefficient, depending on exactly how long `INCOMINGTHREAD()` takes to complete and for the thread to be released, you could exhaust the available threads for your process (and perhaps Windows entirely?) very quickly.

### Excessive threads and RAM

Each Windows thread consumes [`1 MB` of RAM](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273572/125248) and so creating excessive threads has a follow-on effect of consuming excessive RAM.  The OS will try to satisfy your request by requesting memory as well as a logical thread.  As the demand for threads increases and depending on your system and version of Windows, as you approach the RAM limit [certain versions of Windows 10 will start to compress memory](https://superuser.com/questions/1000485/how-to-disable-windows-10-memory-compression) in order to save space.  Now we're in for real trouble as in order to reduce memory pressure, **Windows will compress memory** and this has an **impact on the CPU**!

I've seen quite a few business laptops with say 16 GB RAM being used for development to max out on both RAM and CPU rather quickly with the former having a direct impact on the latter.

### Alternatives

Instead of using `BackgroundWorker` and `new Thread()` you should look into using asynchonous I/O via `async/await` and the equivalent async members of `SimpleTcpServer` (if any).

Alternatively use the older `TcpListener` as it supports asynchronous operation.  This class may not have built-in `Task`-awareness but [you can easily create a Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) for it](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/async-interop-with-iasyncresult.html).

In doing this you vastly reduce the amount of threads your app needs, the CPU time involved, memory requirements and reduction in possible Windows 10 memory compression activity.